# Highlight certain values based on position

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, color

How to highlight or color certain values in a list based on position..
For example x = {1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6}... I want to plot x and highlight values (Red) in a position such as {0,4,5} and others should be black. I want something like highlightedX={**1**,2,3,4,**5**,**5**,5,6}.. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A straightforward solution is to use [MapAt](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) combined with [Style](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html?q=Style). Given your data and a modified highlightpositions (lists in Wolfram are indexed 1 to n)

```
highlightPositions = {1, 5, 6};


MapAt[Style[#, FontColor -> Red] &, x, {#} & /@ highlightPositions]
```

[image]